# How to create function for count number of tags in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

In SQL Server 2014, I need a function that can count the number of tags, and if not equal the number of tags open and close tags, tag if the tag is low, add the appropriate package.

For this example or source code of page of website:

```
<div>
  <ul>
     <li>John</li>
     <li>sara</li>
     <li>mack</li>
     <li>jane<li>
</div>
```

count (`<`) = count (`>`)
count (`<tag>`) = count (`</tag>`)

if count(`<`) < count(`>`) --> add `<` before element of tag
if count(`<tag>`) > count(`</tag>`) then add `</tag>` in correct position or delete.

Comment: SQL Server is a **database management system** - not a HTML processor ......

Comment: no anway?:(((((

Comment: Use a language which do what you want like C#, and then save your results to the database..

Comment: thanks for Your tips @marc_s and tryingtolmprove.

Answer (score 2):

The fact, that you tag your question with `xml` (and the same with your other question you placed shortly) shows clearly, that you have a deep misconception of `XML`...

### XML is not HTML!!!

Many people think, that they are related, almost the same, but - despite the fact, that both use markups in `<>` brackets - they aren't...

We might discuss about `XTHML`, but your examples (here and in your other question) are not *xml-safe*... `XHTML` is an hybrid of `HTML` and `XML`. Every element must be closed correctly, no `<br>` is allows, only `<br/>`, no unclosed tags like `<ul>` in your example... XML is absolutely strict with character escaping, namespaces and nesting hierachies.

SQL Server offers great help to deal with valid XML, but this cannot help you  out. You have to analyse this on string base. But SQL Server is rather poor with string operations and is - for sure! - not the right tool to analyse poorly designed web pages.