# how to get node a and img in sql this example?

Tags: html, sql, xml

my codes :

```
 Declare @htmlXML xml =' 
 <li>
           <a class="group" onclick="changeimage(http://laptopbatteryone.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/1200x1200/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/l/b/lb-ac48-44-back.jpg)" href="javascript:;" title="" >
                <img src="http://laptopbatteryone.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/250x250/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/l/b/lb-ac48-44-back.jpg" alt="Acer Aspire 1420P Battery [6 Cells 4400mAh 10.8V]"/>
            </a>
        </li>
        '



 SELECT  n.c.value('@alt','nvarchar(max)') as Brand
        ,t.v.value('@onclick','nvarchar(max)') as [URL]
        FROM @htmlXML.nodes('li/a') as t(v)
        outer apply t.v.nodes('li/a/img') as n(c)
```

i want to this ouput in sql.
output:

```
url img in <a onclick : http://laptopbatteryone.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/1200x1200/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/l/b/lb-ac48-44-back.jpg

alt img in img tag: Acer Aspire 1420P Battery [6 Cells 4400mAh 10.8V]
```

thanks for your tips my friends

Comment: Hi, as you are new here (btw: Welcome!) please allow me one hint: If your issue is solved, it would be very kind of you, to tick the acceptance check below the (best) answer's vote counter. This will 1) mark this issue as solved 2) make it easier for followers to find the best solution 3) pay points to the answerer and 4) pay points to you. Once you've crossed the 15 points border yourself, you are asked to vote on contributions. This is the SO-way to say thank you. And please have a look onto your older questions too. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beside the fact, that HTML is not XML (and I really start smiling to read such a question from you again, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39546063/5089204) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39434747/5089204)), in this case it might work (still would not advise this)..

```
Declare @htmlXML xml =
'<li>
  <a class="group" onclick="changeimage(http://laptopbatteryone.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/1200x1200/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/l/b/lb-ac48-44-back.jpg)" href="javascript:;" title="">
    <img src="http://laptopbatteryone.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/250x250/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/l/b/lb-ac48-44-back.jpg" alt="Acer Aspire 1420P Battery [6 Cells 4400mAh 10.8V]" />
  </a>
</li>';
```

--The query

```
 SELECT  a.value('@class','nvarchar(max)') AS a_class
        ,a.value('@onclick','nvarchar(max)') AS a_onclick
        ,SUBSTRING(a.value('@onclick','nvarchar(max)'),13,LEN(a.value('@onclick','nvarchar(max)'))-13) AS a_onclick_URL
        ,a.value('@href','nvarchar(max)') AS a_href
        ,img.value('@src','nvarchar(max)') as img_src
        ,img.value('@alt','nvarchar(max)') as img_alt
        FROM @htmlXML.nodes('li/a') as A(a)
        outer apply a.nodes('img') as B(img);
```

The result (row-wise actually...)

```
a_class:   group    
a_onclick: changeimage(http://laptopbatteryone.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/1200x1200/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/l/b/lb-ac48-44-back.jpg)  
URL:       http://laptopbatteryone.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/1200x1200/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/l/b/lb-ac48-44-back.jpg   
a_href:    javascript:; 
img_src:   http://laptopbatteryone.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/250x250/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/l/b/lb-ac48-44-back.jpg 
img_alt:   Acer Aspire 1420P Battery [6 Cells 4400mAh 10.8V]
```